# Filter array of objects on multiple keys

Tags: reactjs, filter, react-table

I have a react table that I am trying to filter on multiple columns using a filter function. If i filter on one column its fine but if i add another column it filters only by that and not both. 
Example would be the name "Scott". I want to filter the first_name column by it and also the biz_name column by it. But when I check the box to change state for that column, it only filters on one. Here is the checkbox in which I have checked state to make sure it is working correctly.

```
                           <Checkbox
                                label="Business Name"
                                onCheck={event => {
                                  if (event.target.checked) {
                                    this.setState({
                                      filterBusinessName: true
                                    });
                                  } else {
                                    this.setState({
                                      filterBusinessName: false
                                    });
                                  }

                                }}
                              />
                              <Checkbox
                                label="First Name"
                                onCheck={event => {
                                  if (event.target.checked) {
                                    this.setState({
                                      filterFirstName: true
                                    });
                                  } else {
                                    this.setState({
                                      filterFirstName: false
                                    });
                                  }

                                }}
                              />
```

And then here is the filter function above the table:

```
let items = this.state.contacts


      if (this.state.term && items.length > 0) {
        let searchTerm = this.state.term.toLowerCase()
        items = items.filter(row => {

          if(this.state.filterBusinessName && row.biz_name){ 

              return row.biz_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)

          }

          if(this.state.filterFirstName && row.first_name){ 

            return row.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)

          }

          if(this.state.filterFirstName && row.first_name && this.state.filterBusinessName && row.biz_name){ 

            return row.first_name.toLowerCase() == searchTerm || row.biz_name.toLowerCase() == searchTerm

          }


        })
      }
```

Comment: Save yourself some duplicated logic by just using the boolean directly: `this.setState({ filterBusinessName: event.target.checked });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this

```js
let items = this.state.contacts;

if (this.state.term && items.length > 0) {
  let searchTerm = this.state.term.toLowerCase();
  items = items.filter(row => {
    if (
      this.state.filterBusinessName &&
      row.biz_name &&
      row.biz_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
    ) {
      return true;
    }

    if (
      this.state.filterFirstName &&
      row.first_name &&
      row.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
    ) {
      return true;
    }

    return (
      this.state.filterFirstName &&
      row.first_name &&
      this.state.filterBusinessName &&
      row.biz_name &&
      (row.first_name.toLowerCase() == searchTerm ||
        row.biz_name.toLowerCase() == searchTerm)
    );
  });
}
```

The main difference here is that the function will only return false if it doesn't match any. Before it returned false immediately if it didn't match one of the filter checks.

There's definitely some optimisation you can do to make this more comprehensible. But it illustrates the idea. Hope that helps

Comment: This worked great. I have some other columns so this may get a little longwinded. I did have to change the last or statement to skip blank ones with || row.biz_name && row.biz_name.toLowerCase() == searchTerm

Comment: Yeah you'll definitely want to refactor this; especially if you intent to increase the complexity. But as you understand to return false only if they all evaluate to false, then you're golden :)